# Lost partition after ubuntu install attempt

Tags: data-recovery, ntfs, partitioning, ext4

I have 500gb HDD with two partitions C and D with the same size (232gb)

I have Windows 10 installed on C

I wanted to install Ubuntu on D

During the installation process I changed the D partition filesytem from ntfs to ext4.

Right after the changing process ended I stopped the installation.

When I boot my pc with windows the D partition does not occur.

When I run Ubuntu from usb the partition mounts empty.

Are my files on D lost?

Is there a way to recover them?

Comment: You have to backup data before reformatting it. Reformatting is erasing. You should always do good backups before any system change. You may be able to use Windows tools to find some data if you did not yet write into that partition. If you just changed most of data may still be there.